How to make nullable context default to disabled in .NET?
On every project where <Nullable> is not specified it sets to enabled which is wrong. Nullable context should be disabled by default. This problem brings problems with Git and working with others because I need to <Nullable>Disabled</Nullable> every project. Even on old .NET Framework projects it is trying to be enabled causing CSC : error CS8630: Недопустимое значение "nullable": "Enable" для C# 7.3. Используйте версию языка "8.0" или более позднюю. [C:\Works\C#\NullableTest\NullableTest.csproj]. My .NET worked fine before. It's .NET bug, but I dont know how to reproduce it to report to .NET team.
I tried to search in Google but seems to be I am only who encountered this problem.

IMHO, "Disabled by default" would be a bad choice. I find a huge benefit by checking the nullability, hence I definitely prefer to have the checking enabled by default.

Are you sure you don't have a global .props file enabling nullable option?

@MarioVernari: The default is for it to be disabled - if there's nothing in any project file, it's disabled. The template project files explicitly enable it, but the "underlying" default is still for it to be disabled.

@JonSkeet you're right. As "default", I mean what VS prepares as "new project". In that case, the nullability is always enabled. By re-reading the post, I realize that the problem is the project file itself, not just what the IDE creates.

dotnet msbuild -pp:out.txt YOUR-PROJECT.csproj

Run this command in your project folder, it will generate an out.txt file. Search "<Nullable>" in the file, the file path containing this property will be listed above. Just remove it from the file.
